# my homepage does not have SSL but another page is ok

Tags: homepage, https

I have use plugin Really simple SSL to enable my site to https. Everything is ok but when wordpress update my site automatically to 4.8.4. Only my homepage do not work for https otherwise another pages are ok. You can see some example in this image:

My homepage when loading: [image]

My homepage when full load: [image]

Another page is ok: [image]

Inaddition infomation:

My homepage: `https://winecellar.vn`

Another page: https://winecellar.vn/ruou-cao-cap/ruou-chi-le

Wordpress version: 4.8.4

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your home is working on SSL but some elements might not be loaded from `https` but `http` like third party images or scripts. Look in source of your home site generated by browser and search for `http:` phrase to find which elements you should fix.

Comment: That's very kind of you. Thanks for your advice. Let me check and try to fix it

Answer (score 0):

You may please use this query on your database to change url from http:// to https://

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = REPLACE(option_value, 'http://winecellar.vn/', 'https://winecellar.vn/');
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value =  REPLACE(option_value, 'http://winecellar.vn/', 'https://winecellar.vn/');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content =  REPLACE(option_value, 'http://winecellar.vn/', 'https://winecellar.vn/');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_excerpt =  REPLACE(option_value, 'http://winecellar.vn/', 'https://winecellar.vn/');
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid =  REPLACE(option_value, 'http://winecellar.vn/', 'https://winecellar.vn/');
```

Comment: If you found the solution I would request you to please accept it ans right answer

Comment: That's very kind of you. Let me check by hand and if it is not possible, I will try your suggest ;). Thanks for your advice.

Comment: One can simply look for URL's with non https in the backend of that specific page.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the page that is not loading secure.  Right click on your mouse, click inspect. click console and you will find the error.  Mine was my logo image was not loading secure.  I simply deleted it from my page and then re-uploaded the same image.  Bam! fixed.  Some other possible places you can locate the error is right clicking the page and view page source.  ctrl "f" and enter http in the search bar.  It will let you find any other place you may have something loading not secure.